# Hide Hour and Minute if 0

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to remove the Hours and the minutes if they are 0

Example ( If hours = 0 )

```
0 H, 1m, 12s
to
1m, 12s
```

and( If minutes = 0)

```
0m, 12s
to
12s
```

But if the hours are

```
2H, 0m, 12s (display like this)
2H, 12s (not like this if the minute is 0)
```

This is what I've tried, but this is so wrong

```
<script>
    var countDownDate = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($getdateinfo)*1000; ?>).getTime();
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var h = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var m = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var s = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        if (h = 0);{
            document.getElementById("tts").innerHTML = m + "m " + s + "s ";
        }
        if (h = 0 & m = 0);{
            document.getElementById("tts").innerHTML = s + "s ";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("tts").innerHTML = h + " h "
    + m + "m " + s + "s ";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: add only if values are greater than 0 i.e. `> 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, only your conditions where badly written :
`if (h = 0 & m = 0);`
You should use two or three equal sign to check for equality, two ampersands for the AND operator and remove the semicolon after the if condition.
`if (h === 0 && m === 0)`

Here is a working example:

```js
var date = "2019-11-15 00:12:12";
var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();

var getRemainingTime = function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var h = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var m = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var s = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  if (h === 0 && m === 0) {
    document.getElementById("tts").innerHTML = s + "s ";
  } else if (h === 0) {
    document.getElementById("tts").innerHTML = m + "m " + s + "s ";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("tts").innerHTML = h + " h " + m + "m " + s + "s ";
  }
};

var x = setInterval(getRemainingTime, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="tts"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is running smootly ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way of doing that with directly using the javascript Date object:

```js
var date = new Date("2019-11-15 00:12:12");

// fix timezone differences
date.setTime( date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );


setInterval(function(){
   var diff = new Date(date - new Date());
   var 
    d = diff.getDate(), 
    h = diff.getHours(), 
    m = diff.getMinutes(), 
    s = diff.getSeconds();   
    
   document.querySelector("#ttl").innerHTML = [
      d > 1 ? (d - 1) + "d" : "",
      h ? h + "h" : (d > 1 ? "0h" : ""),
      m ? m + "m" : ((d > 1 || h) ? "0m" : ""),
      s ? s + "s" : ((d > 1 || h || m) ? "0s" : ""),
   ].join(" ");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="ttl"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a presentation problem, I would fix it in the presentation context (i.e. the string). Here is a quick example.

```js
timeString.replace(/^0H, (0m, )?/, '')
```

This is obviously quick and dirty. You can cascade if statements to build the string, but if you're not calling this a crazy number of times, I find the regex solution easier to understand. Every second is fine.

Note: my answer uses commas because your examples do. But your code does not actually seem to put the commas, so you may want to remove them to make it work.